# Javascript AddEventListener is undefined

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, addeventlistener

try to make it work in firefox, but get: undefined

```
XMLDocument = new XMLHttpRequest();

function startSlides() {
...
XMLDocument.addEventListener('click', processEvent, false);
}

function processEvent() {
//...
}
```

Comment: that's because an XMLHttpRequest() just doesnt have the method `addEventListener`, and listening for a click wouldn't make sense anyway. But it has builtin eventListeners like `onreadystatechange` you can use. Are you sure you want a `XMLHttpRequest`-Object?

Comment: How do you click on `XMLHttpRequest`?

Answer (score 1):

[Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLDocument)

It doesn't support that method.